# Drawing on top of QImage using QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm essentially trying to include an odometer in my application.For that, I want to display a PNG image of an odometer, and then draw a line to represent the needle.I have used QImage on a Qlabel to display the image, however, I can't seem to draw anything on it using QPainter.The following is my code:

```
QImage img(200,200,QImage::Format_ARGB32);
img.load("C:/meter.png");
QPainter paint(&img);
paint.begin(&img);
paint.setPen(Qt::blue);
paint.drawLine(0,0,500,1080);
paint.end();
ui->cont->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
ui->cont->show();
```

I am afraid it might have something to do with qts coordinate system.I know that origin is the top left of your screen and 1 pixel represents 1 increment in the coordinates, is there something I can do to get the location of a point on screen and shift the coordinates to it?

Comment: What do you see on the `QLabel`?  Do you see the image associated with the file `C:/meter.png` as expected?

Comment: @G.M. yeah ,I do see the image.I did find a workaround though, created an empty label and used the QPainter on it , seems to be working that way.